Converting vectorization (raster to vector) with small steps in values in QGIS
I have a raster file that contains water depths in m. The water depths are the only attribute and should be transferred to the vector layer.
The raster files have a cell accuracy of 1m x 1m. I would like to create a vector layer for each cell that contains the respective water depth. When I use the “Vectorize” function, QGIS 3.16 summarizes the water depths in 1m steps. For my task, however, I need the exact values.
Where can I set the accuracy with which my polygons are generated?
I have no programming skills and I'm quite new to QGIS as well.

Can you add a screenshot showing the settings you are using in the tool?


Create a polygon grid with the same extent, resolution (cell size) and CRS as the raster.

Then use field calculator with the expression raster_value ('raster_layer', 1, centroid($geometry))

Make sure to set the output field typt to Decimal number and set an appropriate output field length.



Use the Polygonize (raster to vector) GDAL processing algorithm from QGIS.

that tool does not allow you to specify the quantization step size.
